# Inapproximability Results for APX-hard Geometric Optimization Problems

Tags: lower-bounds, approximation-hardness, computational-geometry

A lot of Geometric Optimization problems are NP-hard and APX-hard to approximate (No PTAS unless P=NP). One example of the geometric set cover problem can be found [here](https://perso.esiee.fr/~mustafan/Research/Papers/separators.pdf). However, it is not easy to prove the lower bound (or inapproximability results) even we know a constant approximation ratio exists.

[Khot](https://cs.nyu.edu/~khot/papers/icm-khot.pdf) showed the connection of UGC and Certain problems in geometry, especially related to isoperimetry and embeddings between metric spaces and their inapproximability results.

[Guruswami et al.](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2740000/2737729/a6-guruswami.pdf?ip=129.110.241.79&id=2737729&acc=CHORUS&key=F82E6B88364EF649%2EA4B876267F8E5B2E%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E6D218144511F3437&__acm__=1534131137_52a9efce6155e7e36ce796c9ef5bc1e8) showed bypassing UGC from Some Optimal Geometric Inapproximability Results.

The [recent breakthroughs for UGC](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/tag/dor-minzer/) improve a lot of inapproximability results such as Set Cover. However, I didn't find their connections with geometric optimization problems.

What are the inapproximability results for APX-hard geometric optimization problems such as geometric set cover, geometric hitting set etc. ?